# Getting the similar column names and count from two tables

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

I have multiple tables in my database(thousands) and I want to check and find if any two given tables have similar column names or not. For this purpose, I created 3 sample tables as follows:

```
    table1(song_cast, song_name, song_size)
    table2(song_size, singer, movie_name, song_cast)
    table3(movie_name, singer, song_name, song_cast)
```

And the output I expect is

```
    |table1 & table2 | song_cast, song_size | 2 #count of common columns
    |table2 & table3 | singer, song_cast, movie_name | 3
    |table1 & table3 | song_name, song_cast | 2
```

I will be running this code in java(NetBeans IDE 8.2) so I'll be getting this output in NetBeans.

Comment: I’m not sure you asked a question.

Comment: @notyou The expected results was his question in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using a couple of [common table expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) the [**`stuff()`** with **`select ... for xml path ('')`** method of string concatenation](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/).

```
;with cte as (
select c.*
from information_schema.tables t
  inner join information_schema.columns c
    on t.table_schema = c.table_schema
   and t.table_name = c.table_name
where t.table_type='base table'
)
, match as (
select 
    tables = l.table_name + ' & ' + r.table_name
  , l.column_name
from cte l
  inner join cte r
    on l.column_name = r.column_name
   and l.table_name < r.table_name
)
select 
    tables
  , columns = stuff((
  select ', '+ column_name
  from match i
  where m.tables = i.tables
  for xml path (''), type).value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(max)')
  ,1,2,'')
  , matches = count(*)
from match m
group by tables
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/TLQ28814

returns:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------------+---------+
|     tables      |            columns            | matches |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+---------+
| table1 & table2 | song_cast, song_size          |       2 |
| table1 & table3 | song_cast, song_name          |       2 |
| table2 & table3 | singer, movie_name, song_cast |       3 |
+-----------------+-------------------------------+---------+
```

Comment: @Sami the rows are in a different order vs the expected results, unless I am missing something else you are hinting at?

Comment: Awesome!! That's exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @SqlZim Yeah, comment removed after I see that was the order :)