# Getting similar column names and count from multiple tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a table called 'SongsMetadata' in my database with 6 columns as shown below (appx 70k records). It contains all songs related information.

[image: SongsMetadata Table]

It is slightly different than the regular database table. The 'File_name' column contains .csv files. Those are the actual tables and values in front of them are the columns in that csv file.

So for '1001186_1_7562755270480253254.csv' record in SongsMetadata table, '1001186_1_7562755270480253254' is the table name and it's columns are '&nbsp', 'name', 'album', 'time', 'price' (these tables contain a lot of garbage values)

My goal is to compare all the tables(in this case .csv files) to get all the similar column names and their count. Now I already have a solution to get common column names and count for normal tables [here](http://rextester.com/TLQ28814). Each table will be compared with every other table. However, I'm not sure how I can achieve the same with .csv tables.

The expected output is:

```
1001186_1_7562755270480253254.csv & 1001186_0_5503858345485431752.csv | &nbsp, name, price| 3 #common columns count
1001186_0_5503858345485431752.csv & 99524146_0_3894874701785592836.csv | &nbsp, name, price| 3
and so on...
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What I think you need to do is "unpivot" that table, then the comparisons will probably be easier. `but` If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the transcription effort? Please don't use images of data, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Comment: What do you want to do with this data? The result of your comparison will be a record set of more than 2 trillion (2,000,000,000) records, assuming all tables have at least one common column.

Comment: You also need put a little effort into the answer **yourself**. This is not a free code writing service. Asking SO community to solve your problem one small step at a time (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47086022/getting-the-similar-column-names-and-count-from-two-tables) is not generally appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution shows how to treat your exsting table so that the wanted matching can occur efficiently, This requires an `unpivot` although the effect of an unpivot is performed by using `cross apply` and `values` which is a simple and efficient method. After that the "matching" is shown, followed by an alternative query for details yo may also find useful. Lastly the new table is displayed just to help visualize what it is.

See the as a live demo at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08b55/9)

**Small Sample**:

```
CREATE TABLE SongsMetadata
    ([file_name] varchar(7), [col1] varchar(6), [col2] varchar(6), [col3] varchar(6), [col4] varchar(6))
;

INSERT INTO SongsMetadata
    ([file_name], [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4])
VALUES
    ('abc.csv', '&nbsp;', 'name', 'price', 'artist'),
    ('def.csv', 'name', '&nbsp;', '&nbsp;', 'price')
;
```

**UNPIVOT Query**

This query moves the column information into a normalized structure to enable the subsequent matching to occur. It is vital to the overall solution. As an added bonus you can mark some column names as "bad" so that these may be ignored later e.g.  `&nbsp;` (which most likely is garbage data)

```
select
    file_name, column_number, column_name
    , case when column_name IN ('&nbsp;','</b>','other-unwanted') then 0 else 1 end as col_is_good
    into SongsMetadataUpivot
from (
    select file_name, column_number, column_name
    from SongsMetadata
    cross apply (
          values
               (1, col1)
             , (2, col2)
             , (3, col3)
             , (4, col4)
         ) ca (column_number, column_name)
     ) d
;
```

**Query 1**:

This is the "matching logic" provided at http://rextester.com/TLQ28814 but applied to the unpivoted songs data, AND it has the ability to exclude column names you simply don't want to consider (col_is_good).

```
with fmatch as (
    select 
        l.file_name + ' & ' + r.file_name AS comparing_files
      , l.column_name
    from SongsMetadataUpivot l
    inner join SongsMetadataUpivot r on l.column_name = r.column_name
                                    and l.file_name < r.file_name
                                    and r.col_is_good = 1
    where l.col_is_good = 1
    ) 
select --* from fmatch
      f.comparing_files
    , STUFF((
            SELECT
                  N', ' + column_name
            FROM fmatch c
            WHERE f.comparing_files = c.comparing_files
            order by c.column_name
            FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
      )
      .value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'') as columns
  , count(*) as num_col_matches
from fmatch f
group by f.comparing_files
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08b55/9/0)**:

```
|   comparing_files |     columns | num_col_matches |
|-------------------|-------------|-----------------|
| abc.csv & def.csv | name, price |               2 |
```

**Query 2**:

This will simply allow production of the column lists, in name order, together with their respective column positions in each file.

```
SELECT
     file_name, ca.*
from SongsMetadata f
cross apply (
  select
      STUFF((
            SELECT
                  N', ' + column_name
            FROM SongsMetadataUpivot c
            WHERE f.file_name = c.file_name
            AND c.col_is_good = 1
            ORDER BY column_name
            FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
      )
      .value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
    , STUFF((
            SELECT
                  N', ' + cast(column_number as nvarchar)
            FROM SongsMetadataUpivot c
            WHERE f.file_name = c.file_name
            AND c.col_is_good = 1
            ORDER BY column_name
            FOR xml PATH (''), TYPE
      )
      .value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 2, N'')
   ) ca (column_names, col_numbers)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08b55/9/1)**:

```
| file_name |        column_names | col_numbers |
|-----------|---------------------|-------------|
|   abc.csv | artist, name, price |     4, 2, 3 |
|   def.csv |         name, price |        1, 4 |
```

**Query 3**:

So you may visualize the "unpivoted" data, the overall solution requires this to occur.

```
select * from SongsMetadataUpivot
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/08b55/9/2)**:

```
| file_name | column_number | column_name | col_is_good |
|-----------|---------------|-------------|-------------|
|   abc.csv |             1 |      &nbsp; |           0 |
|   abc.csv |             2 |        name |           1 |
|   abc.csv |             3 |       price |           1 |
|   abc.csv |             4 |      artist |           1 |
|   def.csv |             1 |        name |           1 |
|   def.csv |             2 |      &nbsp; |           0 |
|   def.csv |             3 |      &nbsp; |           0 |
|   def.csv |             4 |       price |           1 |
```

Comment: Please note this is a revised version that incorporates the "matching" you linked to in the question (& which I had not noticed before he first version). Feedback would be welcomed.